# Как сделать иконку приложения на прозрачном фоне?

Tags: java, android, icon

Хочу сделать иконку приложения на прозрачном фоне. Для этого в фотошопе нарисовал картинку с альфа-каналом. Сохранил в png-файл. Загрузил в Android Studio. Иконка появилась на экране смартфона. Но вместо прозрачности светло-серый фон. Можно ли сделать фон иконки прозрачным и как?

Comment: Да, можно. Именно так и делать - пнг с прозрачным альфа-каналом. Хотя сейчас уже рекомендуют делать свг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляешь в проект изображение. И такие настройки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]